# How can i get the buttons to launch a intent

Tags: android

How can I get the buttons to link to a intent so when user clicks on one of these arrays it would load up a new java file?

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the new Intent related code in your onClick method?

So for example if you want your button click to start a new activity, put this in your onClick method:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
//ADD your parameters here
myIntent.putExtras(parameters);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a button in your XML, then give him an onClick name:

```
 android:onClick="boom"
```

Then in Java file

```
 public void boom (DialogInterface dialog, int item){
   //do something
   }
```